# SharePoint Online - is there a way to create a notification or flow when a file in not modified for three days?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, notifications, modified

I have an excel scheduling tool that I will host on my SharePoint site for others to use on a regular basis. By hosting the files on SharePoint I run the risk that they copy a version to their desktop and stop updating the file I need for them to work on ad I'll be pulling data out of it on a weekly basis.  With this in mind I'd like to see if there is a way to set up an alert or flow for the file whereby it contacts the user after a period of inactivity like three days since they should be in there on a daily basis.

Is this possible? The only alerts I have seen are around when a file is `updated / modified` not when it is not. And I'm not figuring out how to use flow to make this happen either.

Comment: please refer the link https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sharepoint-and-flow/ for detail.

Comment: Yes, trigger a workflow when adding document and pause it for 3 days, then  verify the modified dates and send notification ...

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty straight forward 2010 or 2013 workflow.

1. Store the date last modified,
2. Sleep for three days,
3. Check the if modified date has changed,
4. If not send an email, create a task, etc.

This is a 5 minute test example...

[image: This is a 5 minute test example...]