# Workflow detects no activity, then sends a reminder?

Tags: workflow, email, reminder

I want to create a workflow such that if Activity A isn't completed within 1 day, I will send a notification reminder email to the user to remind him to finish Activity A. How do I go about creating such a workflow?

Comment: This question is almost identical to this one: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218013/sharepoint-online-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-notification-or-flow-when-a-file/233726#233726

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column named "ReminderDueDate" with the following calculation with its result as a date:
=[Due Date]-1

Create a WF that runs on the creation of the item (if the due date is already there) or with the modification (if the Due Date is added later) and pause it until the "ReminderDueDate" column arrives (Pause until date action).